# KivyMD How to change MDToolbar title size and font?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

Im trying to learn KivyMD tools. So i created MDToolBar and it's title changes after some button clicks. Im trying to optimize it's text_size but can't do it.I already tried **font_type:'H1'**, **font_size: '8sp'**. Also i want to change it's font if its possible. Can anyone help me about that. Im sharing minimal code below:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen,ScreenManager
kv = Builder.load_string("""
<SM>:
    P1:
<P1>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDToolbar:
            title: 'TEST'
            font_size: '50sp'
            font_name: 'font1.ttf'
""")
class P1(Screen):
    pass
class SM(ScreenManager):
    pass
class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return SM()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

from kivymd.app import MDApp

kv = Builder.load_string(
    """
<SM>
    P1:


<P1>

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDToolbar:
            id: toolbar
            title: 'TEST'
""")


class P1(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.set_toolbar_font_name)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.set_toolbar_font_size)

    def set_toolbar_font_name(self, *args):
        self.ids.toolbar.ids.label_title.font_name = "JetBrainsMono-ExtraBold-Italic.ttf"

    def set_toolbar_font_size(self, *args):
        self.ids.toolbar.ids.label_title.font_size = '50sp'


class SM(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return SM()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```